# Drawer working during USB debugging, but not working using apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So I have put a list drawer in my home screen. It works perfectly fine when I do USB debugging, but its appearing just grey blankly when I build the apk and run it. I'm unalbe to find the reason for it..

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:pregathi/community-chat/screens/community_list_screen.dart';
import 'package:pregathi/const/constants.dart';
import 'package:pregathi/widgets/home/wife-options-drawer/profile_screen.dart';

class WifeOptionsDrawer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const WifeOptionsDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Drawer(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Profile"),
                leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                onTap: () {
                  goTo(context, WifeProfileScreen());
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Community"),
                leading: Icon(Icons.groups_2_rounded),
                onTap: () {
                  goTo(context, CommunityListScreen());
                },
              ),
          
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot and where you call `WifeOptionsDrawer` widget?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering because you wrap your Column  inside an Expanded widget like this

`Expanded(child:Column([]))`

Flutter is saying: **type 'BoxParentData' is not a subtype of type 'FlexParentData' in type cast**

Solution:

```
Drawer(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
      
          /// your widgets

               ]
            )
        )
     )
 )
```

Comment: Harsha, You forget to mark the solution!